# PHP script needed to create filezilla ftp accounts

Tags: php, ftp, filezilla

Okay, so i have filezilla server software setup, but i want a php script that would add a new user to the xml file that holds the username, password, and folders. i want it to add it to the existing xml file without deleting the current info inside of it. If you know of a available method or script to do this, please send me it or share your knowledge of it. Otherwise if there is another ftp server program that has individual xml or files for each user then please let me know.
Thanks in advance,
Matt.

Comment: Hey, all you need to do is read in the file with php, edit it by adding the necessary data where it needs to go, and then save the file

Comment: can you provide a simple script for me please? i need it to have the username be a variable like when a user enters his/her password it adds it from a requested variable from the page before it.

Comment: oops, sorry, haha i didnt notice that. okay is 75% better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $user = $xml->Users->addChild('User');
 $user->addAttribute('Name', $user_name);

 add_option($user,'Pass',md5($password));
 add_option($user,'Group',null);
 add_option($user,'Bypass server userlimit','0');
 add_option($user,'User Limit','0');
 add_option($user,'IP Limit','0');
 add_option($user,'Enabled','1');
 add_option($user,'Comments','none');
 add_option($user,'ForceSsl','0');

 $filter = $user->addChild('IpFilter');
 $filter->addChild('Disallowed');
 $filter->addChild('Allowed');

 $permissions = $user->addChild('Permissions');
 $permission = $permissions->addChild('Permission');

 $permission->addAttribute('Dir', str_replace("/","\\",$ftpUserFolder));

 add_option($permission,'FileRead','1');
 add_option($permission,'FileWrite','1');
 add_option($permission,'FileDelete','1');
 add_option($permission,'FileAppend','1');
 add_option($permission,'DirCreate','1');
 add_option($permission,'DirDelete','1');
 add_option($permission,'DirList','1');
 add_option($permission,'DirSubdirs','1');
 add_option($permission,'IsHome','1');
 add_option($permission,'AutoCreate','1');

 $speed = $user->addChild('SpeedLimits');
 $speed->addAttribute('DlType', '1');
 $speed->addAttribute('DlLimit', '10');
 $speed->addAttribute('ServerDlLimitBypass', '0');
 $speed->addAttribute('UlType', '1');
 $speed->addAttribute('UlLimit', '10');
 $speed->addAttribute('ServerUlLimitBypass', '0');
 $speed->addChild('Download');
 $speed->addChild('Upload');

 if(!$rv = $xml->asXML($xmlfile)){
  echo ('SimpleXML could not write file');
  return false;
 }


 //Change file encoding from UTF8 to ISO-8859-1
 $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0","ISO-8859-1");
 $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
 $dom->formatOutput = true;
 if(!$dom->load($xmlfile) || !$dom->save($xmlfile)){
  echo ('DOMDocument could not change file enconding from UTF8 to ISO-8859-1');
```

full script from my blog : http://moshez.blogspot.co.il/2013/02/php-filezilla-ftp-server-auto-create.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product. I have added the disclosure for you here. Please keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to manipulate the XML file.

1. Use [simplexml_load_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) to open the file. Make sure you have read/write access to that file.
2. Use the [SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) class to add and delete nodes.

Comment: so can you provide me with some code to get this working? sorry but i'm a newbie at creating php scripts. here is the code in the xml file: http://pastebin.com/d8kD7tEQ
i need it to add a new user after the user "peacons" and i need it to keep the same code at the bottom. i want to use a simple input script like it asks the user for their username and password to create it the info

Comment: Translation: "Please do it for me."

Comment: To put it in a blunt way, yes. I have no idea where to start with such a script. But i am willing to learn how to do it.

Comment: @MattMyers: I am happy to help, but please post what you have attempted or anything that you started with :)

Comment: Well, i would've just went with a simple post php script like this: http://pastebin.com/12PgkzBa 
but it wont keep the same data above it or below it in the xml file.